# Is it right definition of divergence at a point?

Tags: real-analysis

In my text

> > Let D be the domain of function $f$ and $a$ be a cluster point of $D$.
> >
> > '$f$ goes to infinity at a point $a$' is $\forall Y, \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in D : [|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow f(x) >Y]$.

I don't think it is right definition for divergence at a point.

Think about $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $f= 1/x, f(0)=1$.

Here the point $x=0$ cannot satisfy the above definition. Is my assertion right?

Comment: Saying $f$ goes to infinity at $a$ is different from saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Actually, I translated my text into English by the way which I think is natural way. The original definition is "$f$ diverges to infinity at $a$". Is this related something problem?

Comment: No, not really. The point is that in your example of $f(x)=1/x$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist. You can only say that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = \infty$.

Comment: Terminology: "converge" = to have a *finite* limit, "diverge" = the limit is either plus or minus infinity or does not exist. You have a correct definition for the limit to be $+\infty$. (As a variant one takes $0<|x-a|<\delta$ to exclude $f(a)$ from the definition of the limit if $a\in D$).